# Option list which can retrieve from and post to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

can anybody post an code for option list which can retrieve data dynamically from database, and once user selects from option list a record, that record must post it ($_POST) to database.. !!

ive tried this, it retrieves records from db, but not posting it :

```
<?php
require_once "db.php";
if (isset($_POST['a_id']) {
$a = $_POST ['a_id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO projektet
VALUES ('$a')";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

---

HERE IS THE PART SEEMS NOT WORKING :

```
 <form method="post">
<select name="a_id">
      <?php
      $host="localhost";
$username = 'root';
$password = "";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

mysql_select_db('naho',$con);

// Checking connection
if (!$con){
  echo ("Failed to connect to MySQL:. " .mysql_error($con));
  }
else {
     echo("db connect");
}


      $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from `arqitekti`");
      if($result == FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      ?>
    <option value="<?php '.row[a_id];'?>"><?php echo $row["a_emri"];?></option>
<?php }
       ?>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: If it isn't in a `<form>`, it will not post. Please post more of your PHP and HTML to clarify.

Comment: Where is the code for posting?

Comment: @gcarvalho97 ok now i aded <form>, i had the form before just forgot to put it in this post.. but its not working please help..

Salman i assume that the post method is the first part of code above ? ... if that is not the post please help me to build one.. im newbie on php sorry !

Comment: so where should your option be posted? `form` tag should have an `action` attribute equal to the url u are posting to.

Comment: Is the code for POSTing in the same page as the `select`?

Comment: @gcarvalho97 oh god thank u for the answer, ur genious, u saved my whole work bro, yes it worked i just changed the <option value line A LOT OF THANKSSSS

Comment: @TahirSalihu If I helped you that much, then please accept my answer.
Anyway, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php '.row[a_id];'?>"><?php echo $row["a_emri"];?></option>
```

This line looks strange... Shouldn't it be:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[a_id]; ?>"><?php echo $row["a_emri"];?></option>
```

I think that your code is POSTing, but it wasn't getting any value because of the `value` declaration on the `option`s of the `select`. After that change it should work.

PS: If your POST code isn't in the same page as your HTML, it's `<form method="POST" action="YOUR_PAGE">`, not only `<form method="POST">`.